# Rails : carrier wave and heroku without S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am using rails , carrierwave and heroku but right now I don't have a s3 account so I used this configuration 
[How to: Make Carrierwave work on Heroku](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Make-Carrierwave-work-on-Heroku)
It worked very well for files uploaded by the user but It didn't work for files uploaded through seeds 
I am using this syntax
`book.cover = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'photo.jpg'))
book.save!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this instead:

```
file = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'photo.jpg'))
book.cover = file
file.close
book.save!
```

Comment: When you say it did not work, what errors are you seeing?  I'm at a loss to make another recommendation without knowing more about what's going wrong.

Comment: It doesn't upload at tmp , It keeps uploading in public only

Comment: Wait, what's your end goal?  Just to get the file itself into the temp directory?  If so, why not just save the file there?

Comment: I need it dynamic so that the admin can add more books and upload their covers , I need it to upload in temp for just 2 days until I have an access to a s3 account

Comment: It worked 
The problem occurs when I load the seed data from the console instead of rake db:seed , I switched to rake db:seed and it worked very well